# MPAndroidChart unsorted x values

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

MPAndroidChart seems to force you to have data points in sorted for x.

I have a plot that returns to x = zero when the y values are negative the data set would look like this:

```
val dataVals = ArrayList<Entry>()

        dataVals.add(Entry(0f, 0f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(1f, 5f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(2f, 5f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(3f, 2f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(4f, 0f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(3f, -3f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(2f, -3f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(1f, -3f))
        dataVals.add(Entry(0f, 0f))

val dataSet = LineDataSet(dataVals, "datatest")
```

Getting an error code `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException:` which is fixed when the x values are sorted.

The desired plot would look similar too:

[image: desired plot]

Does anyone know of a way this is possible in MPAndroidChart? If not if there are alternatives I am happy to change charting libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have started using HelloCharts which I believe is no longer updated but seems to do the trick for this type of data.

It is not as good for plotting livedata though.